# Populate dropdown box won't show up database

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-select

I'm trying to *populate* a **dropdown** box that retrieve database from **MySQL**. Here are my **form** and **php** files below. It looks alright to me, but I don't get why it doesn't show up any thing when I click on ***submit button***. Is there anything I can do to fix this error? Any correction and suggestion would be appreciated.

`CS_JOBS` table consists of: `job_title`, `category_code` (17, 27, 37....), ...etc.

**connect.php** works fine in this case.

***MY FORM***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action = "csjob.php" method = "POST" name = "jobsearch">
            <select name = "category_code[]">
                <option value = "17">Architecture and Engineering</option>
                <option value = "27">Arts, Design, Entertainment, Sports, and Media</option>
                <option value = "37">Building and Grounds Cleaning and Maintenance</option>
                <option value = "13">Business and Financial Operations</option>
                <option value = "21">Community and Social Services</option>
                <option value = "15">Computer and Mathematical</option>
                <option value = "47">Construction and Extraction</option>
                <option value = "25">Education, Training, and Library</option>
                <option value = "45">Farming, Fishing, and Forestry</option>
                <option value = "35">Food Preparation and Serving Related</option>
                <option value = "29">Healthcare Practitioner and Technical</option>
                <option value = "31">Healthcare support</option>
                <option value = "49">Installation, Maintenance, and Repair</option>
                <option value = "23">Legal</option>
                <option value = "19">Life, Physical, and Social Science</option>
                <option value = "11">Management</option>
                <option value = "43">Office and Administrative Support</option>
                <option value = "39">Personal Care and Service</option>
                <option value = "51">Production</option>
                <option value = "33">Protective Service</option>
                <option value = "41">Sales and Related</option>
                <option value = "53">Transportation and Material Moving</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

***csjob.php***

```
<?php 
    require("connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM CS_JOBS WHERE category_code=".$_POST['category_code'];
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<select name='category_code'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['job_title']"'>".$row['job_title']"</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }
?>
```

So many typos in this question, Here is my actual code that I upload: [a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwlc4x7el7clejh/test.txt)!

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability in your code. What's more important to you... getting a dropdown to display properly, or keeping your server from being pwn3d?

Comment: Enclose the $sql in quotes

Comment: @MarcB: BOTH. I don't see any vulnerability in my code. This one is just a sample. I might be wrong. Thanks

Comment: @bunch: someone fakes a submit and does `submit=0; DROP TABLE CS_JOBS --`. Boom goes your table, boom goes your site.

Comment: @Mihai: Enclose the $sql in quotes? 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM CS_JOBS WHERE category_code=".$_POST['category_code'];

Comment: Well, sorry If I have many questions to you, but in this case it's a dropdown box. How can we possibly `submit = 0` to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 small problems. First one is **in the form**:

```
<select name = "category_code[]">
```

should be

```
<select name="category_code">
```

So without the brackets `[]` in the name and no need for the extra spaces...
The brackets are only needed if you have an option that is has multiple select, and will return an array (hence the brackets). That isn't happening in your case.

And the second problem is what is said before: **in the PHP**:

```
$row['job_title'}
```

should be

```
$row['job_title']
```

So change `}` with `]`

Your third problem has to do with checking the submit:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['category_code'])){
```

Because you don't have a field with the **name** 'submit'. You have a field with **id** submit and **value** submit. But no **name** submit. You can add `name='submit'` to the submit button. Or just go with my proposed change above...

Comment: [newer version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kwlc4x7el7clejh/test.txt)! I already fixed everything you mention above. Thank you! @nl-x

Comment: Good to hear your small problem is solved. Now, you also have one big problem: The SQL injection that is now possible... Just before setting $sql , you should add: `$_POST['category_code'] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category_code'])."'";` This will cover most sql injection related problems.

Comment: That's make sense. I'm going to go add this line of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    require("connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM CS_JOBS WHERE category_code=".$_POST['category_code'];
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){
            echo "<select name='category_code'>";
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  echo "<option value='".$row['job_title']"'>".$row['job_title']"</option>";
                }

            echo "</select>";
          }
    }


?>
```

Comment: notice this `$row['job_title'}` should be `$row['job_title']` =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. You run the query if a particular form field is present, but only run the "display results" code when that same form field is **NOT** present.

Easiest fix: **REMOVE** the `} else {`...

Comment: Yeah I did remove the else statement from my code. It shows up blank in my screen. @MarcB

Comment: add error handling, e.g. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. If that category code is alphanumeric, you need quotes around the value, e.g. `category_code='$val'`. All of your code is assuming the world is perfect and nothing will ever fail. Bad design choice. Assume everything fails, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.